# How to use variable value directly in a dynamically created JavaScript getter?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code for adding getters to an object on the fly:

```js
const obj = {};
const uni = { name1: ..., name2: ..., ...};
for(const nm in uni) {
  const u = obj[nm] = {};
  Object.defineProperty(u, 'value', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    get: () => { return uni[nm] },
  });
}
```

I want getters to return different values, so I want `uni[nm]` to be understood literary, i.e. the first getter would return `uni.name1`, the second `uni.name2` etc.

How do I do that?

EDIT:

I want to dynamically create an object like this:

```js
{
  name1: { get value() { return uni.name1 }},
  name2: { get value() { return uni.name2 }},
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what your goal is. "I want uni[nm] to be understood literary [...]", could you maybe post some code showing what you'd _like_ to work?

Comment: @CollinD - added an edit

Comment: Wouldn't you just change `"value"` to `nm`?

Comment: I need exactly what I wrote, an object that has property "name1", which is an object, that has property "value", and that property is a getter that returns uni.name1 (which will be changed dynamically somewhere else in the code)

Comment: @Mulan - the solution offered doesn't have the structure that I need and it only creates a getter for name2 but name1 is a static property.

Comment: @user9163823 your last comment helps me understand you better. i think my updated answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: What is the problem? Your code seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use `for..in`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/633183). And you pretty much never need `Object.defineProperty`. That's all stone age JavaScript.

Instead use -

- [`for..of` to iterate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) over [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- `get` keyword to define a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```js
const uni = { name1: "foo", name2: "bar" }

let obj = {}

for(const key of Object.keys(uni)) {
  obj[key] = {
    get value() {
      return uni[key]
    }
  };
}

console.log(obj.name1.value) // "foo"
console.log(obj.name2.value) // "bar"

uni.name1 = "zzz"
console.log(obj.name1.value) // "zzz"
```

This can be expressed using [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and -

- [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to extend the definition of an object
- [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) to define a dynamic key -

```js
const uni = { name1: "foo", name2: "bar" }

const obj = Object.keys(uni).reduce(
  (o, key) => {
    return {...o, [key]: { get value() { return uni[key] }}} // extend
  },
  {} // initial object
)

console.log(obj.name1.value) // "foo"
console.log(obj.name2.value) // "bar"

uni.name1 = "zzz"
console.log(obj.name1.value) // "zzz"
```

Comment: yes a stone age api

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this by using the square bracket notation ([]) to dynamically access properties in the uni object, like this: